# is it a good practice to use object (class) for each form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

in general, is it a good practice to use object (class) over direct variable?

for example:

**case 1**

```
class Person {
 firstName: string;
 surname: string;
 likes: string[];
 dislikes: string[];
}

let person1 = new Person();

<input ([ngModel])="person1.firstname" placeholder="Please enter your name here">
```

**case 2**

```
let firstName: string;
let surname: string;
let likes: string[];
let dislikes: string[];

<input ([ngModel])="firstName" placeholder="Please enter your name here">
```

Comment: This sort of question isn't really appropriate for here. It's asking for general advice on something that is strongly opinion based and likely requires a lot of explanation around the context in which one solution might be used over another. E.g. you're asking about an object for data but not placeholders. Also, ECMAScript has a class syntax for convenient creation of native objects, but not classes in the classic sense. At least you used "good practice" over "best practice". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is always good to have Interface/Class on the data which you want to bind. When you want to bind complex data it is always good to go with Class.

If you are binding one or two variables, you can do without a class/Interface.

Comment: hey Sajeetharan, just to see I understand you correctly. You are saying that it is good practice to use interface/class in small object, and class in big complex cases. While variable is an option for one or two variables. Am I am correct?

Comment: yeah exactly, always go for class/Interface if you are building an enterprise level application

Comment: hmm i see and if I expect this project to grow, therefore I should always go for the class/interface. ok thanks.